# ParametricNDSolve with known solution at one limit

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

The ODE I wish to understand is the following:

```
pdeg = (-2 (β - γ ρ) g[p] - 2 p^(γ/(-1 + γ)) (-1 + γ) \
  ζ^(-(γ/(-1 + γ))) ρ^(γ/(-1 + γ)) g[p]^(γ/(-1 + γ)) + 
   p (2 (M λ - p λ + μ) Derivative[1][g][p] + p σ^2 (g^′′)[p])) == 0
```

The parameter of interest is $\lambda \geq 0$. For $\lambda = 0$, there is a known solution to the ODE:

```
g0[p_] := 2^(1 - γ) ζ^γ ρ^-γ ((-2 β +
  γ (-2 μ + 2 ρ + (1 + γ) σ^2))/(-1 + γ))^(-1 + γ) p^-γ

pdeg /. λ -> 0 /. g -> g0 // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

I have been unable to find an analytic solution for $\lambda > 0$, so I'm turning to numerical methods. The function `ParametricNDSolve` seems ideal for this purpose, but looking at the documentation, I cannot directly see how to use it.

The problem is that for my second-order ODE, I would need to specify two boundary conditions. However, I do not know what these are, only that at $\lambda = 0$, the function should take the above form. Is it possible to set up `ParametricNDSolve` so that it starts with this known solution at $\lambda = 0$ and then numerically solves as $\lambda$ is slowly increased?

Here are a set of constants to help with the numerical analysis:

```
CONS = {ρ -> 0.02, γ -> 0.7, μ -> 0.03, σ -> 0.2,
  β -> 0.017, ζ -> 0.7, M -> 1}
```

for which the above expressions simplify to

```
pdeg = 2404.23/(p^(7/3) g[p]^(7/3)) - (3 g[p])/500 + 
  p (2 (3/100 + λ - p λ) Derivative[1][g][p] + 1/25 p (g^′′)[p]) == 0

g0[p_] := 108.062/p^(7/10)
```

In this case, it should be sufficient to numerically solve for $p \in (0, 2]$, and $\lambda \in [0, 0.5]$, say. Any insight is appreciated!